# How to capture the text of an Select option?

Tags: javascript, html-select

So I have this:

```
<select id="list">
    <option value="1">This is Me</option>
    <option value="2">This is You</option>
    <option value="3">And this is Mr. Nukem</option>
</select>
```

How would I go about grabbing the 'text' of the options here? The problem is, it needs to be 'dynamic', in the sense I need the text for the currently selected option...

I know a manual, static way of getting the text...

```
document.getElementById('list').options[1].text
```

That will grab "This is You"... But how do I get it for the currently selected option? Since I can't simply use:

```
document.getElementById('list').value
```

As that will grab the number... :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var text = list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;
```

See (for example) here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement

Comment: @Abhishek: No, that's not possible. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list option[value='2']").text()
```

You can use this jQuery line and it will solve your problem.

In this an element with id list which has a property value equal to 2. What you want is the option child of the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, you can try something like this:

```
$("#list").change(function() {
    alert($(this).find("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").text());
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/MWu9f/ for a working example.

Comment: Nah, thanks for the response... (uber fast, not to mention) but someone else already got it for me... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery solution is like this:

$("#list option:selected").text()

Comment: Could you please provide a working example of what you are proposing in the answer? Eg. a jsfiddle or similar. I am unsure whether this is a working solution, and if it is, a full example might be useful for others to help understand how exactly does it work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).